# Catch link clicked on PDF in Page Viewer

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, pdf, popup, page-viewer-web-part

Im displaying a PDF document in a Page Viewer with custom Links in it. When you click a link, the page viewer will show the specific url in the page viewer. In some cases i have a sharepoint site in a sharepoint site, which is not very pretty.

I would like to catch the clicked links with javascript and open a popup instead of browsing in the page viewer.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I embedded the PDF in a html object instead of a page viewer. Now i am able to attach an eventhandler to the PDF and communicate with it.
The "site in site" problem is also gone.